# Chain rule to find derivative of $\ln(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

ok so by using the log rule where the power becomes the coefficient, we get $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)$

$dy/dx=1/(1/2)x$

my question is,since it is a logarithmic function of a square root function of $x$, can we use the chain rule to get the same answer as above?

Comment: do you mean $\ln(\sqrt{x})$ or $\sqrt{\ln x}$? Your question suggests the latter one, but in the title, you use the former one.

Comment: ahh sorry, i mean the 1st one. Square root of x, not the whole function

Comment: Be careful: you want a $2$ in the denominator of $dy/dx$, not a $(1/2)$.

Comment: @Ryangomez Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln(x^{\frac{1}{2}})) & = \dfrac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln(x)) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \\
& = \frac{1}{2x}
\end{align}

Keep it simple, no chain rule needed here, as long as you know $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln (f(x))) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: This is what the OP did...

Comment: Perhaps you should write $\ln(x^{1/2})$ not $\ln(x)^{1/2}$. It's a bit ambiguous what you have now

Comment: @Student The OP's final answer, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}x$ is wrong.

Comment: I assumed this was another typo, since he states that he used the power rule and denoted that result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(\ln f(x))’=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}=\frac1{2x}$$

and we can use any rules for derivatives to obtain the same result, for example by product rule

$$\ln \sqrt x=\frac12\cdot\ln x=\left(\frac12\right)'\cdot \ln x+\frac12\cdot(\ln x)'=\frac1{2x}$$

or by quotient rule

$$\ln \sqrt x=\frac{\ln x}2=\frac{\frac1x\cdot 2-(2)'\cdot \ln x}{4}=\frac1{2x}$$

and so on.

In this case the interpretation of $\ln \sqrt x=\frac12 \log x$ as

$$(cf(x))'=cf'(x)$$

is of course the most effective and clever.

Comment: @rapidracim no it isn't

Answer (score 0):

We can compute the derivative using the chain rule: the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{x}$, the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$. Applying the chain rule gives

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}^2}$$
and since $x > 0$, this simplifies to $\frac{1}{2x}$.